# Does someone know a good workflow with yeoman and netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm having some problem to import the angular-seed project generated from yeoman to netbeans, the only way that seems possible is to create a new web project and import the files generated to it. Does someone know a better workflow with yeoman and netbeans?

Comment: On Netbeans 8.0.1 I just prompted for a New Project > HTML5 >' HTML5 Application with existing sources', selected the project and it should load on netbeans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been in the same shoes man. 


read these...
https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular 
Yeoman generator for AngularJS - lets you quickly set up a project with sensible defaults and best practices.


It'll download and setup everything . Plus a generator to generate your controller , route etc... read its documentation .